# how to force user to scroll to view content in html

Tags: html, css

Sorry I am very new to html and css

I am making a website in html and css and want user to scroll down to view the content below. There is only logo and tagline on the screen. If I try to add image it shows below the logo, but I don't want to do that. Is there any way to force user to scroll to view the content further?

Thanks and once again, sorry.

Edit: here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>MSN</title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
</head>
<body class="body" style="overflow-y:hidden">
<center>
<div class="main"><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<img class="logo" src="logo.png">
<div class="tiles">
<button class="t1"></button>
<button class="t2"></button>
<button class="t3"></button>
<button class="t4"></button>
<button class="t5"></button>
<button class="t6"></button>
<button class="t7"></button>
<button class="t8"></button>
</div>
</div>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.body {
background-color: #ffffff;
background-image:url(background.jpg);
}

.logo {
position: absolute;
left: 42%;
top: 25%;
}

.tiles{
position: absolute;
bottom: 20%;
white-space:nowrap
}

.t1 {
background-image:url(tiles/t1.jpg);
height:119px;
width:210px;
border:0px solid #ffffff;
}

.t1:hover{
background-image:url(tiles/t1-1.jpg)
}
```

Comment: You need to make your logo and tagline container take 100% of the window height.

Comment: Can we have the code your facing problem with?

Comment: Let me see if I understand. You have stuff on teh top of the page, but you want me to see whats below it except that the stuff on top takes up too much space?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood, is it something like that ?

```css
#foo { 
  height: 100px; /* You need a fixed height for scrolling over it */ 
  background: #ddd;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="foo">
  <img src="http://sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/logos/so/so-logo-med.png" alt="logo" />
  <p>HELLO,<br>I'm hide<br><br>Peace.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I doesn't work for although it is the thing that I want. If I add the code it just put a scrollbar of height 100px but don't the whole content.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap your logo in a div and give it a height of 100vh.

HTML:

```
<div class="logo_container">
    <img class="logo" src="logo.png">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.logo_container{
    height:100vh;
}
```